# Limit execution time of a piped program

Tags: c, time, pipe, fork

I want execute a Linux command in a C program and read (parse) `stdout` from this command in the program. The code below works but I don't know how to limit execution time of the command, in addition to the string and bytes read limits. Any ideas?

```
FILE *ps_pipe; 
int bytes_read;
int nbytes = 100;
char *my_string=NULL;
char message[1024];
message=sprintf(message,"any command here");
ps_pipe = popen (message, "r");
my_string = (char *) malloc (nbytes + 1);
bytes_read = getdelim (&my_string, &nbytes, "delimiter_word", ps_pipe);
pclose(ps_pipe);
free(my_string);
```

Comment: [alarm](http://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man3/alarm.3.asp) is your friend.

Comment: Either that or just close the pipe. The child process will terminate with a EPIPE/SIGPIPE.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I used alarm, it works, but i dont know why pclose in alarm handler does not execute properly with file descriptor, which is global var and is used in another function only with open and fread.

Comment: [You can't call `pclose` in a signal handler.](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/SIG30-C.+Call+only+asynchronous-safe+functions+within+signal+handlers)

Answer (score 0):

You could do that with select(). Select can "wait" on one or more file descriptors for an event to happen (readable, writable, ...), with an optional time-out. Since it operates on file descriptors, you'll also need fileno(ps_pipe).

Keep in mind however that you won't be able to kill the forked process easily, because popen hides certain details of the child process. If you need such control, you'll need to use lower level functions fork(), pipe(), dup(), exec(), wait() and possibly kill().